# A div in right with restricted width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, right-align

Page width available is 1600 px, I was trying to align the div in right, and with max-width: 1200px. But that is not happening.

```css
.csystem {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end
}
```

```html
<div class="csystem">
  <h1>Yes</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon on justify content: flex-end on your css.

Comment: I think semicolon is a non issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `align-items` not `justify-content` because you changed the `flex-direction` to column

```css
.csystem {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* margin-left: auto; */ /* If you wnat the div to be on the right */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="csystem">
  <h1>Yes</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A similar solution not working [here](https://codepen.io/codeispoetry/pen/ExaJxmX)

Comment: it's working but the main container doesn't have the full width, if you want to container  `.csystem` to be on the left as well add `margin-left: auto` see in this example https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: margin is the key. Flex is not useful here simple display block and margin-left can do the needful.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.csystem{
    float: right;
   max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: can we do it through flex?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/30pzwoyv/1/ see this jsfiddle